# Can't find name 'ChangeDetectorRef' in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, typescript2.0, ionic3

I'm migrating an Ionic 2 app to Ionic 3, with Angular 4.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, Inject, AfterViewInit, forwardRef, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

[...]

```
  constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => TimelineComponent)) private _parent: TimelineComponent, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.window = <Window>window;
}
```

And i'm getting an error : Can't find name 'ChangeDetectorRef in this constructor :(

Here my package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "4.0.0",
"@angular/common": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.0.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
"install": "^0.8.8",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.3",
"npm": "^4.5.0",
"pdfmake": "0.1.26",
"rxjs": "5.1.1",
"smoothscroll-polyfill": "0.3.4",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"typings": "2.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"  },
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
"typescript": "~2.2.1",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-help": "^1.6.1",
"gulp-inject-string": "^1.1.0",
"gulp-load-plugins": "^1.4.0",
"gulp-replace-task": "^0.11.0",
"gulp-war": "^0.1.4",
"gulp-zip": "^4.0.0"
```

},

Here my errors in Chrome
[image: Here my errors in Chrome]

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: I don't have a stacktrace it's in the error list of the main page :
Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'ChangeDetectorRef'.
.../my.component.ts

    constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => TimelineComponent)) private _parent: TimelineComponent, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.window = <Window>window;

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges

Comment: This code worked before. Can you explain me instead of pasting a simple link ? Thanks for the -1 btw

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: I'm getting an error : Can't find name 'ChangeDetectorRef in this constructor :(

Comment: I don't understand, if you have a problem or error post the MCVE

Comment: Why are we only seeing the cd: ChangeDetectorRef argument in the error you posted but in your code you have a previous argument which is not visible in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgrated with the new version and now it works :)

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "4.0.2",
"@angular/common": "4.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
"@angular/core": "4.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
"@angular/http": "4.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.0.2",
"@angular/tsc-wrapped": "4.1.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
"ionic-angular": "3.1.0",
"install": "^0.8.8",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"ionicons": "~3.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.3",
"npm": "^4.5.0",
"pdfmake": "0.1.26",
"rxjs": "5.1.1",
"smoothscroll-polyfill": "0.3.4",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"ng2-pdf-viewer": "1.0.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.5"  },
```